# Google Cloud Registry Quota and Metrics Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

My image pull request at an GCR repository are being rejected due to Quota Exceeded, I'm suspecting that some of our processes are requesting image hashs too often. These processes are distributed at multiple kubernetes clusters, cloud providers and regions.

```
Unable to fetch image "gcr.io/wise-woodford/adapter:v1.4.0":                                                                                                  
      failed to resolve image to digest: GET https://gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3Awise-woodford%2Fadapter%3Apull&service=gcr.io:                                      
      unexpected status code 429 Too Many Requests: Quota Exceeded.
```

Traffic by credentials would probably help finding the culprit.
Unfortunately the Container Registry API area, metrics section, shows no traffic at all, no matter the time frame chosen.

[image]

Questions:

- how is that API enabled?
- is there an alternate method to see who is consuming those requests?

Comment: The Container Registry API is enabled on the [Marketplace](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/marketplace/product/google/containerregistry.googleapis.com) or in its [Overview](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/apis/api/containerregistry.googleapis.com/overview). 
You can also try to create a [Cloud Monitoring dashboard](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/monitoring/) to see the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, GCR quota is not visible in the UI. GCR limits requests per IP address.

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/quotas